# Certain songs not playing through MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm creating an app that can playback songs from Apple Music using the MPMusicPlayerController for people with a subscription.

I've run into a problem where certain songs fail to play whilst others work fine and I'm not sure why this would be the case.

The ID for a song that wouldn't work is `627511704`. I've double checked some songs that don't work using the iTunes search API just to confirm that they do actually exist on the store which they did.

Here's the code where I attempt to queue the `MPMusicPlayerController` with an ID

```
func playWithAppleMusic(track: Track) {
    guard let id = track.appleMusicID else { return }
    self.appleMusicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()
    self.appleMusicPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
    self.appleMusicPlayer?.setQueueWithStoreIDs([String(id)])
    self.appleMusicPlayer?.currentPlaybackTime = 0
    self.appleMusicPlayer?.repeatMode = .none
    self.appleMusicPlayer?.shuffleMode = .off
    self.appleMusicPlayer?.play()
    self.startTimer()
}
```

I have also tried using an instance of `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()` instead but that also did not work and wouldn't queue the song in the Apple Music app either.

Anybody know if I am doing something wrong here or is it just Apple's API being buggy again?

Thanks

Comment: Check to see if the tracks are m4p (copy-protected).

Comment: Are you sure the songs that are playing are from Apple Music and that you haven't just purchased them previously?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the comment and yes definitely haven't bought them before. @amergin How would I check that? They are all results returned from the iTunes search API

Comment: Check the MPMediaItem.mediaType property maybe. I don't use MPMusicPlayerController, I use AVPlayer stuff. If I were you I'd try out other music apps on the app store and see if they play the tracks. Examine the track in the Music app as well, that might show you something. Also do a get info on it in iTunes on your Mac.

Comment: seeing the same behaviour here. Any progress on what might be causing this?

Comment: For me, content purchased from Audible is no longer working, but audiobooks purchased via iTunes are working.

Comment: In my case, it turned out that I was trying to play tracks with incorrect IDs for my locale. e.g. I was trying to play the French 'version' of a track in the UK